# When doing ajax call user session becomes inactive

Tags: jquery, ajax, liferay, liferay-dxp

In Liferay 7.4. in custom portlet whenever I do Jquery ajax call it calls c/portal/expire_session and user session becomes inactive and have to do login again.

Checked all portal_ext and portal.properties files and filters and hooks. still no luck.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], see [ask].

Comment: Thanks for response… From Liferay 7.4 when doing jquery ajax call it’s calling expire session url after that user gets logged out

Comment: That's hardly a [mcve]. Please read [ask], consider to take the [tour], and edit your question with detailed steps.